# update table using variable sprintf using Join

Tags: php, mysql, variables, join, printf

Im trying to set a variable using sprintf via a Join Query, then update each time this appears in the table using the ID loaded into the query.

The update works fine if I use a slightly different query but one that gives an identical set of results, so have come to the conclusion Im doing something silly.

Here is a selection below:

```
//below is a simpler version of what I would like to work with the update

$sql=sprintf("SELECT `test`.`id` FROM `test` JOIN `test2` ON (test.agent=test2.user) WHERE `test`.`type`='new' AND `test2`.`note` = 'p';

//this is what works, even though the output (list of test.id) is identical to above

$sql=sprintf("SELECT `id` FROM `test` WHERE `test`.`type`='new' AND `agent`='test.user';


//here is my update that works with the second select
if($ref_id = mysql_one_data($sql)){
        $updateSQL= sprintf("UPDATE `test` SET `type`='testdata', `priority`=%s, `note`=%s WHERE `id`=%s;",SQLVal('100', "int"),SQLVal($note, "text"),SQLVal($ref_id, "int"));
        $result = mysql_query($updateSQL) or die(mysql_error());
        $processed=TRUE; $result="updated";
        $count_converted++;
        }
```

Any ideas?  I'm at a total loss!  As I said both queries give 100% the same output, so the variable produced should be the same right? and so if one update works when it finds a corresponding value the other should too.

Comment: You're missing an end quote and parenthesis on your first two sprintf's. Typo in the quesiton or a "real" problem?

Comment: "quesiton"... typical when asking about a typo ;-)

Comment: Typo, it's where I simplified it and removed another variable being set as text at the end.  It would have had this at the end- ", SQLVal($ticket_id, "text"));

Comment: Worked it out, there was a bit that i didnt copy where I missed the "<table>." out in the select.  This was fine when running the query in PHP MyAdmin and MYSQL workbench but putting into PHP it wasnt having any of it